# Spritesheet editor which can automatically replace identical sprites?

Tags: sprite, image-sprite

I have a spritesheet (used by a simple 2d pixel game):

[image]

Water is animated (each water sprite is different), grass remains the same.
I need to replace each grass sprite (32x32 px) with a different sprite. So after editing it will look like this:

[image]

Of course I can do it manually in any graphical program.

But I'm looking for a spritesheet editor that's dedicated to this kind of work - one that can do it easier or more automatically, so I don't have to manually paste same replacement sprite multiple times and struggle with positioning it correctly by hand.

Comment: Wouldnt it be easier to export the spritesheet from an animation? Thisway layers are easy to manage

Comment: Probably, but program to edit this game's files can export/import only this format.

Comment: Just cut it up with imagemagic